# defining unique name for Kafka file sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a service which generates XML string and sending it to Kafka topic which should than generate XML file.
At the moment I am using Kafka FileStreamSink connector which generates the file with predefined fixed name. 
The filename of that XML file should be generated according to the XML content, how can i do so?

below is my FileStreamSink connector configuration with the predefined filename.

```
{
    "name": "file_sink_stream_01",
    "config": {

            "connector.class": "FileStreamSink",
            "group.id": "file_sink_stream_connector",

            "tasks.max": "1",

            "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
            "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",

            "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
            "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",

            "topics": "stream_userid_stream",
            "file": "file.xml"

    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do so with the file sink - the file name is static and even an SMT wouldn't let you redefine it

Note: json converter would output json, not xml

If you absolutely need this, you could try Apache Nifi

Comment: Also note that the FileStreamSink is _not_ designed for production usage.

Comment: @Robin-Moffatt,  can you explain why this is not designed for production use? I saw this statement around the web but with no real explanation.

Comment: @Erez it only deals with single files, doesn't track progress, cannot guarantee order of messages written to that file from multiple partitions, and does not deal with structured data... Those are just a few reasons I can think of